# Simple Case query fails logic - what am I missing?

Tags: sql-server, case

Why would this "Fail", if foo is less than 40 it should be "OK"

```
SELECT foo = '30', case when 'foo' >= '40' then 'Fail' else 'OK' end as 'Test'
```

So my actual query is (where ArrivalDate is a datetime):

```
SELECT Distinct [Title]
      ,DATEDIFF(day, [ArrivalDate], GetDate()) AS 'DaysOldSinceArrival'
      ,case when 'DaysOldSinceArrival' >= '40' then 'Fail' else 'OK' end as 'Test'
```

I believe the 'DaysOldSinceArrival' output must be a string and this is why the compare is not working.  Is this failing for the same reason, if so, how do I make the 'DaysOldSinceArrival' an actual INT?

Comment: i have updated the answer, you can check the updated query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not correct, I feel you are trying to do something like following.

```
DECLARE @FOO INT
SET @FOO =30
SELECT @foo , case when @foo >= 40
then 'Fail' else 'OK' end as 'Test'
```

Output

```
(No column name)    Test
     30                  OK
```

> Issues in your query. You are comparing string `'foo'` with a string
>   value `'40'`, which is not ture.

**EDIT**

After looking your update, it seems you want to do like following

```
SELECT *,
(case when DaysOldSinceArrival >= 40 then 'Fail' else 'OK' end) as 'Test'
FROM
(
    SELECT Distinct [Title]
    ,DATEDIFF(day, [ArrivalDate], GetDate()) AS 'DaysOldSinceArrival'
    FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
  ) T
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine in SQL, it shows the proper result under 'Test', however when I try to call the recordset for it simliarly to all the other columns in VBScript, the 'Test' column is blank.  So I end up with all the columns populated except status in the VBScript output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are comparing a string to an INT which is implictly converted to a string and thus desn't equal your other string. You could use a CTE which can be more clear than a derrived table for some.

```
;with cte as(
SELECT 
   Distinct [Title]
   ,DaysOldSinceArrival = DATEDIFF(day, [ArrivalDate], GetDate()))

select 
   *
   ,Test = case when DaysOldSinceArrival >= 40 then 'Fail' else 'OK' end
from cte
```